# Sending email in a Multi-tenant environment

Tags: java, email, smtp, gmail, multi-tenant

I'm working on setting an email service for a multi-tenant application. How this can be set to ensure that the sender is the tenant email (or alias). Can this be done without persisting the tenant email password?

I'm using Java and Spring `JavaMailSender`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need tenant's password for sending the email. Normally, in such a multi-tenant environment, you will sending emails using a RELAY server.

In case you are using a RELAY server, you can define a sender email address for all your tenants which your RELAY server can authorize just with the email address and no password.